# Replace commas in a cell in excel with another text in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

In cell A1, I have the following numbers separated by commas:

`10,2640,3,400`

Please note that:

- will always be numbers
- the unit, tens, hundreds, thousands are arranged in no particular order
- numbers separated by comma could be more than the 4 above; could be blank, 1 or more

What I want with an excel **formula** if possible:

Insert `<<<>` at the very beginning and then replace all commas `,` with `,<>` (or insert `<>` after every `,`)

- blank remains blank
- `10,2640,3,400`  becomes `<<<>10,<>2640,<>3,<>400`
- `100`  becomes `<<<>100`
- `1540,24,334,4,100000`  becomes `<<<>1540,<>24,<>334,<>4,<>100000`

So far I've only been able to add the first `<<<>` and replace the first occurrence of `,` with `,<>` with the formula below:

`=IF(COUNTBLANK(A1),"","<>"&REPLACE(A1,SEARCH(",",A1,1),1,",<>"))`

Result `<>100,<>2640,3,400`

Any help on how to extend this formula (or a different formula) will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out the [SUBSTITUTE function](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-substitute-function).

```
CONCATENATE("<<<>",SUBSTITUTE(A1, ",",",<>"))
```

The first argument to CONCATENATE may be tweaked (e.g. drop last 2 characters) depending on if you want the behavior specified in the description or that shown in the examples (at the time of answering, the two are not consistent with each other).

Comment: the "&" character does the same as the concatenate function.  An alternate form of writing the same formula is `"<<<>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",",<>")`

Comment: @ForwardEd They may have the same function, but code readability is important in supporting collaborative development & maintainability.  Folks newer to Excel formulas (e.g. don't know SUBSTITUTE) might find CONCATENATE easier to clearly understand.  Thanks for noting the alternate!

Comment: THANK you very much @WBT and ForwardEd